# Can I wire 1 more bluetooth antenna to extend the range?

Tags: antenna, bluetooth

I want to extend my bluetooth range for my Sony Playstation 4 to be able to play in different rooms. I have added an external antenna by taking off the original one and replacing it with a removable one. Unfortunately it wasn't enough and the signal is still not as good as I would like to have. My next thought is to put 2 antennas on the same wire and put them in different rooms. Will it work? Won't the signals transmitted by the 2 antennas interrupt each other?

Answer (score 1):

*..put 2 antennas on the same wire ...Will it work?*

No it won't as antennas need to "see" the correct impedance (usually 50 ohms)  in order to work properly. By simply adding an antenna in parallel you **disturb** that "characteristic impedance" and the will actually make the antennas **less efficient** so things will get **worse**.

*Won't the signals be caught by 2 antennas interrupt each other?*

No it does not work like that, but it will definitely not work for the reasons I explained above.

For a proper 2 antenna solution there need to be **two** antenna connections present on the PCB. And even then, it can be that only one connector is physically connected.

**If** there is an antenna connector on the PCB you could possibly use a better antenna. You can use a WiFi (2.5 GHz) antenna as Bluetooth uses the same frequency band.

But ultimately, Bluetooth isn't designed to work well through (concrete) walls so your goal of being able to extend the range so that you can cover multiple rooms is simply a bridge too far for Bluetooth.

Comment: Not really correct. The antennas still work, they still present the correct impedance to their own coax. At the radio there is a mismatch and half the signal is lost. The antennas are unchanged, and work exactly as before, just there is signal loss.

Comment: @HenryCrun I disagree, the antennas will be loaded with the wrong impedance so there will be power mismatch also at the antenna. You are very wrong in stating that an antenna's (behavior) remains unchanged when it is not terminated properly. Antennas are an interface between air (EM waves) and an input impedance (the transceiver) and the complete path needs to be properly matched. Any mismatch results in efficiency loss. Also saying "half the signal is lost" means that you do not understand RF, how much signal is lost is impossible to say beforehand.

Comment: It is perfectly easy to calculate the power loss by connecting a 25ohm load to a 50ohm resistive source. Note that radios are designed to work with a 50ohm load, but they do not actually have a 50 ohm impedance themselves. The transmitters have a low impedance (just like the mains at home) to get good efficiency. The receivers may be noise matched for best noise figure, not power transfer. A transmitter may produce more power into 25 ohms than 50.

Comment: @HenryCrun OK, what you write goes against much of my 20 years of RF experience. *The transmitters have a low impedance* Hmm, so you obviously never designed a PA of the type which is on the average Bluetooth or WiFi chip? To save power these mostly have current outputs so are high impedance and need to be matched.

Comment: I will note that I have done what the OP suggests (3 antennas), for similar reasons. It worked. I suggest you have not done this, and are theorising. I do not disagree that performance will be reduced in some sense. BUT it will still work, and it can work in a way that is an improvement for the OP, even if overall coverage area is less

Comment: Commercial transmitters are designed to have an output impedance of 50 ohms because of the importance of using coaxial cable for the transmission line.  Not all RF generating methods will put forth an output impedance of 50 ohms.  In making this comment, I actually have no idea what a Bluetooth or WiFi impedance actually is but I do agree that it should be matched.  I have been building antennas for almost 60 years, all HF, as a ham radio operator and getting a good match is one of the most important objectives.

Comment: Another comment -- I don't see any comments on the importance of using multiple antennas as a means of producing higher gain.  AM stations do this regularly but primarily to create directivity which is the inverse of gain.  Ham radio operators do it with multiple separate antennas such as stacked Yagi antennas to boost gain sometimes 10 to 15 dB on HF antennas.  Higher frequency like BT or WiFi are easier to boost gain in this manner or by using multiple director elements because the wavelength is very small (at least in comparison to HF).

Comment: *actually have no idea what a Bluetooth or WiFi impedance actually is but I do agree that it should be matched* Often the RF ports on BT/Wifi chips are 50 Ohms or some value between 50 and 200 ohms. That could be differential (meaning not single ended). Then a balun and/or matching network might be needed to get to 50 ohms. Usually antennas are 50 Ohms but of course there can be exceptions.

Comment: *multiple antennas, directivity* Indeed possible **but** the system needs to support it. Bluetooth doesn't as far as I know. WiFi does support multiple antennas and directivity. Note that for each antenna a separate transmitter is needed as each antenna needs to transmit a (slightly) different signal. In cellular (UMTS, LTE) this is also used to electronically "focus" on a handset. Drifting off topic here :-)

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie -- in commercial and amateur radio, multiple separate transmitters are not used but rather the antennas are fed out of phase with each other but such phase differences to accomplish the goal of directivity.  Using multiple receivers though is very common to achieve diversity reception to enhance weak signal copy.  Indeed, my own transceiver has two totally separate receivers (Elecraft K3).  Yes, off topic.  I am headed upstairs to eat breakfast.

Answer (score 0):

If you get the antennas closer to the user it can work.

You should connect the two antenna cables together *right* at the BT module. Overall, you will lose signal in the cable length and also half to mismatch (as 2x 50 ohm antennas=25 ohms). You should *not* try to tee one antenna off the cable of the other.

There may be an area equidistant between the antnnas where the signal is flaky, because it cancels out every half-wave (50mm).

So what you will get is two smaller areas around the antennas, which work. But overall, a smaller total area.

That might be exactly what you need - two puddles of signal exactly where you need them, or a figure 8 shape.

The mismatch could be fixed with a quarter wave matching section or wilkinson coupler, if you got technical.

But you can just join them. It's considered "wrong" and you lose signal, but it does still work. Low power transmitters like BT can't be damaged by doing this.

---

A probably better alternative is to get a single directional antenna, and point it at the distant part of the house. Simplr directional antennas, are not nearly as directional off the beam as you imagine.